# Using own variable in WebDriverWait. Selenium. Python

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

```
link = div.find_element_by_tag_name('a')
```

How can I use this in the statement

```
link = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located(div.find_element_by_tag_name('a')))
```

This, doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### visibility_of()

[`visibility_of()`](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_support/selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.html#selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.visibility_of) is the expectation for checking that an element, known to be present on the DOM of a page, is visible. Visibility means that the element is not only displayed but also has a height and width that is greater than 0. element is the WebElement returns the (same) WebElement once it is visible.

```
selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.visibility_of(element)
```

---

As `visibility_of()` takes an element as an argument, you can use the following [Locator Strategy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

```
link = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of(div.find_element_by_tag_name('a')))
```